# Phonegap: How can I add a hash value to index.html inside webview via Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

I created an iPhone app with PhoneGap.

On application start, PhoneGap starts the web view with the index.html file from the www directory.

That works good so far.

However, I have the required that I need to do a hashchange to index.html via Objective-C when a certain event occurs (in this case a push message).

**Example:**
`index.html` needs to be changed to `index.html#foo` during runtime

So, how can I change the hash value via Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
UIWebView *webView = ...
NSString *hash = ...

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.hash = '%@'", hash]];
```